# How to change list of tuples to same tuples? [python]

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have list like this:

```
l = [("a"), ("b"), ("c")]
```

and i need to have:

```
l = ("a"), ("b"), ("c")
```

Someone know some reasonable quick way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with same tuples?

Comment: So you want to turn a list of strings into a tuple of strings?

Comment: It's just `tuple([("a"), ("b"), ("c")])` to turn the list of strings into tuple of strings.

Comment: @DarrylG that wont work. ```('a', 'b', 'c')```

Comment: @BuddyBob -- why not?  `l = ("a"), ("b"), ("c"); ll = tuple([("a"), ("b"), ("c")])` Then `l == ll` is True.

Comment: @DarrylG OP wants `l = ("a"), ("b"), ("c")`  you give `('a', 'b', 'c')`

Comment: @BuddyBob--`("a"), ("b"), ("c")` is `"a", "b", "c"` which is `("a", "b", "c")`.  This can be seen by using the module dis (the disassembler) to check the Python disassembled code.

Answer (score 1):

You said you have a list of tuples. What you've shown isn't actually a list of tuples. It's a list of strings:

```
>>> [("a"), ("b"), ("c")]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> type(("a"))
<class 'str'>
```

I think what you meant was `l = [("a",), ("b",), ("c",)]`. That's a list of tuples.

To change your list of tuples into a tuple of tuples, you simply do:

```
>>> tuple(l)
(('a',), ('b',), ('c',))
```

EDIT - Note, that the following literal syntax:

```
l = ("a",), ("b",), ("c",)
```

Is a tuple of tuples.

Comment: This would be the closest to the OP's desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want

```py
>>> want = ("a"), ("b"), ("c")
>>> want
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

You say you have

```py
>>> have = [("a"), ("b"), ("c")]
>>> have
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Use `tuple()` to get what you want from what you have:

```py
>>> tuple(have)
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> tuple(have) == want
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a list of strings to a tuple of strings simply use tuple()

```
>>> l = [("a"), ("b"), ("c")]
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> 
>>> tuple(l)
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
l = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
a,b,c = l
# now a = (1,2), b = (2,3), c = (3,4)
```

Otherwise the other answers should be able to help you. You might also want to look into the `*` operator ("unpacks" a list, so e.g. `[*l,(4,5)] == [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]`) as well.

Either way, you might want to improve your phrasing for any other question you intend to post. Give concrete examples of what you want, what you tried and what (unintended) effects that had.